# Bug in mice:pool(): doesn't work for for censReg/tobit anymore ("No glance method recognized for this list")

Tags: r, r-mice

Since I have updated my version of R to 3.4.4., the mice::pool() function does not work for my censReg object anymore.

I build a mice object using

```
  library(mice)
  library(censReg)
  library(lattice)

  set.seed(1234)
  m<-matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:10), 100, replace = T), 10) # Create data with NA's
  df<-as.data.frame(m) 
  df$V1 <- c(1,0,6,0,0,0,3,NA,0,4) # censor V1
  imp <- mice(df) # impute object
```

Afterwards, I perform a censored regression analysis of the imputed object and try to pool the results:

```
fit <- with(imp,  censReg(V1 ~ 
                            V2 +
                            V3+
                            V4                              
                           , left = 0
                          , right = Inf))
s1 <- pool(fit)
```

While this was not a problem before I updated my R version, I now get the error code:

```
Error in glance.list(X[[i]], ...) : 
No glance method recognized for this list
```

I tried to use the tobit() function from the AER package instead of censReg, but here I receive a similarly obscure error message:

```
Error in if (!is.null(newnames) && length(newnames) != ncol(x)) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I also tried to recover an older version of R, but for every version earlier than 3.4.0. the censReg installation fails and for every version from 3.4.0. onwards the installation succeeds, but I get the error message mentioned above whenever I try to pool the miced censReg analyses.

Does anybody have an idea where the bug comes from and how one can solve it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I get the same error using mice 3.0.9 and R 3.5.1; you could try posting this question on https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/issues. They should be able to help you

Comment: Ah thanks, will do that!